# $f:\mathbb{R}-\{\frac{1}{n}, n\in \mathbb{Z}\}\to \mathbb{R}$

Tags: derivatives

Do is differentiable function at point $x=0$?

$f:\mathbb{R}-\{\frac{1}{n}, n\in \mathbb{Z}\}\to \mathbb{R}$

$f(x)=x$

In a the book was written $x=a$ be Interior point $D_f$

So: function $f$ not differentiable at $x=0$

is it right?

Comment: Does $\Bbb Z$ include $0$?

Comment: It's just a matter of definition. I would say that the function is differentiable at $0$ because the limit $\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(h)-f(0)}{h} = 1$.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your definition of differentiablity.

For the basic definition, we can only talk about the differentiablity of a function at an interior point of its domain. In this case, we cannot talk about the differentiability of $f$ at $0$ at all.

Sometimes we say a function $F$ is differentiable at a point $x\in D_F$ if there is a neighborhood $U$ of $x$ such that there exists a differentiable function $\tilde F:U\to\mathbb R$ such that $\tilde F=F$ in their common domain. In this case, we can see that $f$ is differentiable everywhere in its domain.